# Login and Logout in master page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, authentication

Here login and logout buttons in master page. In login page is using FormsAuthenticationTicket and HttpCookie, so in master page I want to check the forms authentication and then display logout if is authenticated and hide login. If not authenticated display login and hide logout. How can I do that?

Login:

```
com.CommandText = "select [id], [username],[password], [type] FROM [users] WHERE [username] =@username AND [password]= @pass";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName.Text);
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", Password.Text);
 //  conn.Open();
 SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();

 if (rd.Read())
    {

    var _id = rd["id"].ToString();

    var _fname = rd["username"].ToString();

    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(

           1,
           _id,
           DateTime.Now,
           DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
           true,
            "." + _fname,
           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hashed_ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashed_ticket);

        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            Response.Redirect("UserProfile.aspx");

       }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
}
```

Master page HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="login" runat="server"
PostBackUrl="~/Login1.aspx">Login</asp:LinkButton> </li>
<li> <asp:LinkButton ID="Logout" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" onclick="Logout_Click" style="text-align: right">(logout)</asp:LinkButton></li>
</ul>
```

Code behind Master Page:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Logout.Visible = false;


    }
    else
    {
        Logout.Visible = true;
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath] != null)
        {
        FormsIdentity user = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = user.Ticket;
        login.Text = "You are logged-in  " + ticket.UserData.Split('.')+ "!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<%if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{%>
    <li> <asp:LinkButton ID="Logout" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" onclick="Logout_Click" style="text-align: right">(logout)</asp:LinkButton></li>
<%}
else
{%>
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="login" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Login1.aspx">Login</asp:LinkButton> </li>
<%}%>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Algiri It was a typo, I fixed it.