# How to hide "log out"-button when using the"FormsAuthentication"-method to log in?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a "log out"-button in a masterpage that I want hidden when the user is logged in.

The login-functionality is very simple and is implemented by the following code in the Web.config-file (as well as some simple code in a log-in page):

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="KunstCookie"
           loginUrl="InnUtlogging.aspx"
           defaultUrl="SalgsOversiktAdmin.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30" path="/" />
  </authentication>
```

I manage to log in and out using a user name and password I set up on a log-in page.

I am trying to hide the log-out button while I am logged in by including the following code in the masterPage.master.cs file:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["kunstCookie"] != null)
    {
        ButtonLogout.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

But the button is still there when I am logged in. There is no error message when I load the page. Its almost like the cookie file doesn't exist or something.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do this. Instead of:

```
if (Session["kunstCookie"] != null)
```

I inserted:

```
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

I found the answer here:

[Login and Logout in master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578199/login-and-logout-in-master-page)